# Why is my ginput code not working in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ginput

I am wanting to use the package ginput from matplotlib in python3 to be able to click on points on my data graph and the x,y coordinates are displayed and saved to a variable. My code for using ginput is below.

```
plt.ginput(n=0, timeout=0, show_clicks=True, mouse_add=1, mouse_pop=3, mouse_stop=2)
x = plt.ginput(3)
print("clicked", x)
plt.show()
```

My output only displays my graph and when I hover my mouse over data points it does not show as an arrow and the clicks do not work. It just keeps running only displaying my graph not any coordinates.

Comment: don't you get error message when you run script in console/terminal/cmd.exe ?

Comment: why do you use `n=0` ? Why do you use `ginput()` two times ? Why don't you use only `x = plt.ginput()`